# Is it a good practice to manually change foreign key values?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

Is it a good practice to manually change foreign key values for models without involving Activerecord? Is this approach faster, because fewer database calls are being performed?

Examples:

```
## Changing value by hand
item = Item.all.first
item.list_id = params[:other_list_id] # Assigning to foreign key field directly
item.save

## Changing value with the help of Activerecord
item = Item.all.first
item.list = List.find(params[:other_list_id])
item.save
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Absolutely no difference, apart from the db call.

It depends on how you want to treat the query - it's going to be more conventional to use the *object* to populate the associative data, but it's by no means essential.

We often merge params:

```
def update
   @item = Item.find params[:id]
   @item.update item_params
end

private

def item_params
   params.require(:item).permit(:item, :params).merge(list_id: params[:other_list_id])
end
```

In the end, the best thing you can do is make your code *efficient*... getting the most out of the least.

Answer (score 0):

The approach may be fast as you are right, fewer database calls are required, but what you are not doing here is checking that the list_id does actually exist first which could cause errors later on. (Usually I would never trust the user input and always validate it first.)

If taking this approach, it may be worth adding some validation to the Item model to check that the list id does exist before saving the item.

Scott

Comment: 1) Security is not a concern for my current project. 2) list_id will always exist, because it's a model field, I'm just trying to overwrite whatever is there. Thanks for response!

Comment: @AlexanderLomia but if I manually change `params[:other_list_id]` to -1, it will update the record with a wrong id, and will lead to application crashes.